# android.R.color.primary_text_light deprecated: What to do now?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am working on a custom android view.

I want to draw a text with the standard android text color.
Therefore I wanted to use android.R.color.primary_text_light, but the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#primary_text_light) says that it's deprecated and "a text color from your theme" should be used.

What does that mean? I just want to use the normal android text color, which is also used when just adding a textview to the layout.

Comment: that means you should use your application theme color. Which are in colors.xml file in your project under res/values tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android have deprecated it because they want you to use your application theme colors rather then using android native colors. You can find your application theme colors in the following path:

**`project/app/res/values/colors.xml`**

in that file you will have few colors declared already like:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#2196f3</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976d2</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryLight">#B3E5FC</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#03A9F4</color>
<color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
<color name="secondary_text">#757575</color>
<color name="icons">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="divider">#BDBDBD</color>
```

So have to use these colors now. If you want to change the color value just change the value and you can have your desired color.